# Use question mark in like parameter for MS Access DB on ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access, parameters, sql-like

I have an ASP.NET web site and use MS Access for the database. I have a table in the db for storing Mobil number. I want to show records if the second digit is number 4.

This query worked fine in Access but in ASP.NET returned zero records.

```
select  telnumber
from numberlist
where telnumber like ?4%
```

I send `?4%` as parameter to OleDbCommand but no result returned!

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in the query is actually the parameter place holder and not the wildcard for a single character. The place holder will be replaced with your parameter value when the query is executed so your query becomes `like ?4%4%`

The parameter value you pass should be `'?4%'` and your SQL statement should be

```
select telnumber
from numberlist
where telnumber like ?
```

---

[Retrieving Data Using the AccessDataSource Web Server Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Because the [AccessDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.accessdatasource(v=vs.100).aspx) control extends the [SqlDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource(v=vs.100).aspx) class
>   and uses the System.Data.OleDb provider, you specify parameter
>   placeholders using the "?" placeholder character. The
>   [System.Data.OleDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb(v=vs.100).aspx) provider does not support named parameters; instead,
>   the parameter values are applied in the order they are specified in
>   the parameters collection.

Answer (score 0):

I find own question's answer!
for search by character index by SQL or access data-source I must replace ? with _ and it worked!